# How To Convert string he,llo from hello

Tags: php

how to display `he,llo` from  `hello` in php.

I have used function `substr_replace("hello",",",2);`

but only displayed he, i need result `he,llo`

Comment: what's the logic behind?

Answer (score 4):

You should use **`str_replace`** like in my example.

**Example:**

```
str_replace("hello","he,llo","hello");
```

Comment: I'd love to upvote this answer for humour sake :D

Comment: i got inspired by Martin Solveig..

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer

```
substr_replace("hello",",",2,0);
```

Comment: +1 Your simple answer works. Don't know why you don't get upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Why your solution doesn't work:

`substr_replace("hello",",",2);` replaces `llo` with `,`. That means it replaces the `substring` from the index `2`. That's why your solution didn't work.

What's the solution:

```
        `substr_replace("hello",",",2,0);` instead.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo str_replace("he", "he,", "hello");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

> str_replace:
>   Replace text within a portion of a string

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$str = "Hello" ;
echo substr($str,0,2) . "," . substr($str,2) ;
```